# Widget is null when Adapter is generating view and the user is on another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager to display 3 fragments in a main activity. I have a CardView that displays when a RecyclerView (populated by an adapter is empty. My Code works fine when on launch I am on the screen where the CardView and RecycleView appears but if I am any of the other fragments when the Adapter is loading - I get a null pointer error and the app crashed. Either bull on the CardView or on the RecycleView or both. In the code below for the fragment homeAgenda and noEvents cause the app to crash when identfied as null. There is a delay in load because the app syncs with Google Calendar and then displays in the RecyclerView at which point if I am on another fragment - the app crashes.... please refer ti runuionThread

I have used findViewByID and done a null check but the app keeps crashing - how can I avoid this scenario?

```
 private fun getEvents(){
    val noEvents = view?.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.no_events)
    val homeAgenda = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.homeAgenda)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        Log.d(
            TAG,
            "Time current: ${calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}, ${calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)}, ${
                calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)
            }"
        )
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity())
        val events = db.getEvents(calendar.timeInMillis)
        val listOfEvents = ArrayList<MyEvent>()
        for (event in events) {
            if (event.isPrimary) {
                listOfEvents.add(event)
            } else {
                listOfEvents.add(0, event)
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getEvents: ${events.size}")

        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            if(listOfEvents.size != 0) {
                noEvents!!.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                noEvents!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            val recyclerView: RecyclerView? = homeAgenda
            recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            recyclerView.adapter = EventsAdapter(
                requireContext(), listOfEvents,calendar.timeInMillis
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log/ Stacktrace below - error hitting on this line from the above code noEvents!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE and when I remove this then it hits on the recycleView being null...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: , PID: 6492
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Fragments.Home$getEvents$1$1.run(Home.kt:294)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please show your stack trace.

Comment: Hi Christian, have updated the post..